# Automatically run Makefiles when doubleclicked

Tags: c, windows, makefile

Is there a way to have Makefiles run automatically (then pause at the end) when doubleclicked in Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Makefiles themselves are not meant to be executable, but there is a way to automate the making of programs by using a batch file (for Windows) or a shell script (for Unix).  Place the following in a notepad text file and rename it to a .bat extension file (like makeprogram.bat):

> make 
>   pause

This .bat file is executable, and if placed in the same folder as a makefile will compile according to said makefile using the make command.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a program to run `make` and them assign it as default program to run when the `Makefile` is clicked. Like this(Visual Studio) using C:

```
#include <shellapi.h>

int main(void)
{
    ShellExecute(0,0,"make.exe",0,0,SW_SHOWNORMAL);
}
```

Using a batch file is a lot simpler:

```
make
pause
```

Comment: Problem with your first solution is that you can't assign a default program to `Makefile` because it has no extension.